# How to create a custom phone number directive using intl-tel-input lib

Tags: angularjs, directive

I am currently trying to create a custom directive that would initialize an input with the following lib : [intl-tel-input](https://github.com/Bluefieldscom/intl-tel-input).

So I downloaded the required `.js` file with Bower:

```html
<script src="bower_components/intl-tel-input/build/js/intlTelInput.min.js"></script>
```

Then I create my input :

```js
input type="tel" class="form-control" id="tel" name="tel" ng-model="informations.tel" ng-keyup="checkPhoneFormat()" ng-click="checkPhoneFormat()">
And I'm initializing it at the beginning of my controller like this :

angular.element('#tel).intlTelInput({
    validationScript: "../../bower_components/intl-tel-input/lib/libphonenumber/build/isValidNumber.js",
    preferredCountries: ['en', 'fr']
});
```

My problem is that when I'm trying to access the `informations.tel` model, it is always undefined. It seems that the input do not update the model value on the fly.

So I have to write something like this to bind the actual value of my input field with my non updated model value:

```js
$scope.checkPhoneFormat = function(){
    $scope.informations.telephone = angular.element('#telephone').val();
...}
```

It could be okay, but I would like to create a custom directive to initialize such inputs, something like:

```js
app.directive('phoneInput', function (PhoneFactory) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            phoneNumber: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            element.intlTelInput({
                 validationScript: "../../bower_components/intl-tel-input/lib/libphonenumber/build/isValidNumber.js",
                 preferredCountries: ['en', 'fr']
            });

            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
                console.log(viewValue);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

But as `ngModel` is undefined, the initialization function is never reached.

How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are right that the model does not get updated automatically.
You could make a directive like this

```
app.directive('intlTel', function(){
  return{
    replace:true,
    restrict: 'E',
    require: 'ngModel',
    template: '<input type="text" placeholder="e.g. +1 702 123 4567">',
    link: function(scope,element,attrs,ngModel){
      var read = function() {
        var inputValue = element.val();
        ngModel.$setViewValue(inputValue);
      }      
      element.intlTelInput({
        defaultCountry:'fr',
      });
      element.on('focus blur keyup change', function() {
          scope.$apply(read);
      });
      read();
    }
  }
});
```

that could be called like this

```
<intl-tel ng-model="model.telnr"></intl-tel>
```

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KZzTURvvcEWl7XiNzLwC?p=preview)

Comment: It is working pretty well :), and do you have any idea how I could return to the view the validity of the input in order to set an error such as : ```<p class="help-block error" ng-show="registerForm.tel.$error.invalidPhoneFormat && model.telnr">Enter a valid tel number</p>```

Comment: Since you already have required the ngModelController in your directive you can just call the $setValidity method. You can read here how it can be used: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

Answer (score 4):

There is a new directive called international-phone-number @ https://github.com/mareczek/international-phone-number

Please checkout, any contributions are welcome

Comment: How to get only Country code (Dial Code) of selected filed ?

Answer (score 4):

A few of us used Marks's directive, but the lack of testing and jquery's required position in the head was causing issues so `ng-intl-tel-input` was created:

https://github.com/hodgepodgers/ng-intl-tel-input

Check it out, it's unit and functionally tested with protractor
Play with it here:

http://hodgepodgers.github.io/ng-intl-tel-input/

Comment: This directive is require jQuery too, isn't' it?

Comment: True, jquery is still required. This addressed the issue of having to place jquery in <head>

Answer (score 2):

Mark's directive worked for me:
https://github.com/mareczek/international-phone-number

One issue with intl-tel-input (at least with v3.6) is that it doesn't format the phone number you initialize it with properly* unless you have a plus sign ('+') before it. This leads to funky behavior for my users. I store my phone numbers normalized (without the plus sign) in my database so I need a hack to get around this. Instead of formatting on the server, I opted to format the phone number on the front-end. I added the following to Mark's directive to get the behavior I needed:

```
var makeSureInitialValueStartsWithPlusSign = function() {
  var clear_watcher = scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(changes) {
    elem_val = element.val();
    if (elem_val && elem_val[0] != "+") {
      element.val("+" + changes);
      clear_watcher();
    }
  });
};
makeSureInitialValueStartsWithPlusSign();
```

Thanks Mark

*By properly I mean converting '19734566789' to '+1 973-456-6789'. int-tel-input converts '19734566789' to '1 973-456-6789' (without the pus). When a user goes to edit it, they experience whacky behavior because the plus is not there.

Comment: How to get only Country code (Dial Code) of selected filed ?